# Custom layout ignores size of composeable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm currently playing around with custom Layouts in Jetpack Compose. This is what i got so far just for testing:

```
@Preview(widthDp = 1000, heightDp = 1000)
@Composable
fun MyLayout() {
    Layout({ Box(Modifier.size(48.dp).background(Color.Blue)) }) { measurables, constraints ->
        val placeables = measurables.map { it.measure(constraints) }
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            placeables.forEach { it.place(0, 0) }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is that the `Box` fills the whole layout and not only it's size of `48.dp`. Can someone explain to me why this is? I read [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom#create-custom) about creating custom layouts but couldn't find anything usefull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Layout` size is determined by the size passed into `layout(width, height)`.

Your `Layout` doesn't have any modifiers, that's why it has `maxWidth`/`maxHeight` constraints equal to available spacing. Using `layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight)` has the same effect as applying `Modifier.fillMaxSize`. Actually with `Modifier.fillMaxSize` your'll set both max and min constraints to the available size.

To solve this you have two options:

1. Apply `Modifier.size` to the `Layout` itself, instead of applying to the `Box` - in this case max/min constraints will be `48.dp`
2. Calculate layout size depending on placeable. The actual code depend on what layout do you expect to get. Your code looks like `Box` analog, so you need maximum of all placeable sizes:

   ```
   layout(placeables.maxOfOrNull { it.width } ?: 0, placeables.maxOfOrNull { it.height } ?: 0) {
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your second approach but it did not work. I added two boxes to the layout, one with `48.dp` and the other with `96.dp`, tried to place them both at (0,0) but both take up the same amount of space. For now I just want something similar to a `FrameLayout` where elements are stacked on top of each other.

Comment: @Cilenco Not sure how exactly have you tried. [This code](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/8c272bc12be2b1c4ee12b9f9fe79f511) produces [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UgIm.png) to me, which I find expected

Comment: You are right, my fault. I had `@Preview(widthDp = 1000, heightDp = 1000)` on my method. After removing `widthDp` and `heightDp` it's displayed correctly. Also tested it on my phone which works as well. Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the blue box fills the entire `Layout` is because of a combination of a few things: (1) you specify dimensions for the `@Preview` annotation, (2) you use the `Layout`'s constraints unmodified to measure the box, and (3) the use of the `size` modifier.

Because of point 1, the constraints of the `Layout` will have both the minimum and maximum set to what was specified in the Preview dimensions. Because of point 2 those strict minimums and maximums are used to measure the box. And because of point 3 the incoming constraints take priority over the requested size (that's the way the `size` modifier works).

Mitigating each of those points will solve your problem.

As you already found out from one of the other answers, removing the width and height from the preview annotation will make those seem right. That is because without the width and height specified in the Preview annotation, the constraints will have a minimum of 0, so the child measurable are now allowed to take the size they want.

The recommended way though is to fix point 2: change the constraints to fit the requirements of your custom layout before you pass them to the measurables' measure methods. In this case, you probably want to create a copy of the constraints and set the minimum width and height to 0.

And finally you can fix point 3 by using `requiredSize` instead, which will size the measurable to the required size regardless, even though it will still communicate to its parents a size that's within the constraints. This is usually not recommended in production code because it makes sizing absolute, but for a preview it should be fine, and for tests it could even be desirable.